# Old popular question - marked as duplicated after I answered on it

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Recently I've found an old but popular and relevant [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363247/android-how-to-enable-or-disable-adb/41542129#41542129) question with very poor answer to it.

So I've added a new answer with a clear explanation of every step,
included relevant references for each step
and copy-pasteble code snippet.

But after I did that, the question marked as duplicated - which states:

> This question already has an answer here: `link`

Now I have checked that linked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314145/looking-to-enable-and-disable-toggle-adb-or-usb-debugging-using-command-line-o) as well, and with all respect to the answers there they don't give the full information or the steps that I added ditto.

So even that I clearly stated at the top of my answer:

> For the future readers ...

Those future readers might never see the answer - just because of `duplicate` mark...

So my simple question is: **What should I do about it**?

Comment: Just a note, *all* posts are for "future readers", you don't have to explicitly address them.

Comment: Why not move your answer to the duplicate? If it's better than the others it should rise to the top.

Comment: @meagar Understood, but I write it to make people understand that I don't negate an already existing posts

Comment: @jonrsharpe I thought about it, but in my opinion those questions are different, therefor the answers may also differ. In the second one - the OP asked for common line solution, but in my solution - I move the user to enable the ADB (when needed)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've merged the two questions together, the only other answer in the closed-as-duplicate question was a link to the first question's accepted answer, which never should have been posted or accepted in the first place.

Your answer (and the other answer) have now been moved to the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314145/looking-to-enable-and-disable-toggle-adb-or-usb-debugging-using-command-line-o), and the previously accepted answer from the dupe has been deleted.

---

Addressing your larger question of what one should do in this situation:

It was somewhat of a mistake on your part to post the answer to that question in the first place. Given that its accepted answer was a link to an identical question with more and better answers, you should have followed that link, posted your answer on the better question, and then voted to close the first one as a dupe.

Having already posted your answer, you could have deleted it (and lost your two upvotes) and reposted it on the other question, or flagged it and asked for a moderator to merge the questions together. Since the questions were nearly identical and the answers were literally the same answer, with one linking to the other, the merge request would probably have been accepted by whichever moderator handled the flag.

Comment: Maybe I'm not long enough in the stack to see the whole picture, but are you sure that this is the right solution?
Because as I wrote in comments - in my opinion the questions are different, please note that the `other question` is command line oriented and the `deleted` is not

Comment: Given that the accepted answer was identical in both cases, I think it's safe to assume the closed question was also looking for a CLI-oriented answer.

Comment: I completely understand what you mean - about the fact that OP of `deleted` question has accepted the other one. But I originally have found this question when needed another approach (Which I created and later posted there as my answer). Therefor for me the second question wasn't relevant - while the first one was. And also note that in that question there was above 15000 views - which maybe means the question interpreted as different by many users (not just me).

Comment: @NikitaKurtin if after all of those views nobody had previously seen fit to comment that the link in the accepted answer didn't help, maybe not. But now there are both approaches on one question, so it's easy for other people to find whichever helps them.